# ECS deployment gets stuck on In progress

Tags: amazon-ecs

So I created this ecs cluster with ec2 a few months ago and it worked for a while,I made some changes a long the way and it stopped working. The service wasnt ready for production so I didnt mind. But here is the issue the deployment gets stuck In progress for days, it doesnt even fail I dont know why. I just rebuilt my ecs cluster with a different terraform script just in case.
[image]
I just checked my ec2 instance is connected to my cluster
[image]
I dont see any events as you can see. Also I dont see any logs in cloudwatch. Just my old logs from when the service used to work. I am loosing my mind because I have deleted the server and recreated many times. I was using private subnet and I just changed that to public just in case.